# For what $x_{0}$ this sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$X_{n+1} = X_{n}^2 - X_{n}/2, \quad n \geq 0$$

For what values of $x_{0}$ this sequence converges? For what value?

I think to solve this problem separating it in three steps:

**The series is constant.** Ok

**The series is crescent:**

$X_{n+1} > X_{n}$

And for this case we need to require this:
$X_{n} - X_{n-1} > X_{n+1} - X_{n} $

**The series is decrescent:**

$X_{n} > X_{n+1}$

And for this case we need to require this:
$X_{n} - X_{n+1} < X_{n-1} - X_{n}$

Now, i think this is not the best approach, it is long and extremely easy to be made an algebraic mistake. There is another way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For what values $x_0$, does the sequence $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - \dfrac{x_n}{2}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773353/for-what-values-x-0-does-the-sequence-x-n1-x-n2-dfracx-n2-conv)

Answer (score 1):

We can test for monotonicity like this:

$x_{n+1}-x_n={x_n}^2-\frac{x_n}{2}-x_n=x_n(x_n-3/2)$

This means that for $x_0<0$ and $x_0>3/2$ the sequence is monotonically increasing, and for $0<x_0<3/2$ the sequence is monotonically decreasing. The sequence is constant (and therefore converges) for $x_0=0$ and for $x_0=3/2$.

If we take the case where $0<x_0<3/2$, we just need to show (using induction) that $0<x_n$, because we know that for these values of $x_0$ the sequence will be monotonically decreasing. Therefore, by finding a lower bound we can prove that the sequence converges. Then we can prove that the limit of the sequence when $n$ goes to infinity will be $0$.

For $x_0<0$ we can do the same but this time finding an upper bound (that upper bound will be zero), as the sequence is monotonically increasing for those values of $x_0$.
Lastly, for $x_0>3/2$ it is easy to show that the sequence will diverge, because it is monotonically increasing and there are no possible upper bounds.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use induction to show that $X_{n+1} \geq X_n$ for all $n$ if $x_0 \geq \frac 3 2 $ and $X_{n+1} \leq X_n$ for all $n$ if $x_0 \leq \frac 3 2 $.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fixed points are $0$ and $\frac 32$, one common technique is to subtract them from both sides of the recurrence equation, and you get

$$x_{n+1} -\frac 32 = \left(x_n-\frac 32\right)(x_n+1)$$
$$x_{n+1} - 0 = (x_n-0)\left(x_n-\frac 12\right)$$

Now you need to consider the following intervals for $x_0: (-\infty, -1], (-1, 0], (0, \frac 12], (\frac 12 \frac 32], (\frac 32, \infty)$

Can you start from here?